# Overview (or list/index) of Javascript libraries, with description of what it's used for

Tags: jquery, dojo, javascript-framework, mocha.js

I'm trying to learn more about the javascript libraries available and what each might be used for. I.e., are they all for manipulating HTML or are some of them designed for other tasks like database access.

*Use Case* : If I want to do X, how do I know what library to look in?
Where X =

- a particular effect (like a transition effect for making a Window appear)
- a special control (like a Rich Text Editor)
- Unit Testing
- Store data offline

I've seen the list on Wikipedia but it doesn't have descriptions of each. And the examples are sort of hit and miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best examples I've found are:

- http://javascriptlibraries.com/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Npm is the Node.js package manager and package index.

https://npmjs.org/

Jam is a package manager and package index. Jam is an extension of npm packages and in most cases a Jam package can also be installed with npm.

http://jamjs.org/

For Javascript libraries outside of Node.js, some suggest searching github.com or google.com.